# C++ bring methods and fields into external scope, without explicit references

Tags: c++, scope, closures, using, member

I would like a behavior similar to what closures do implicitly, bringing variables into scope, without having to declare references explicitly

Example struct

```
struct A{
    T x;
    void g();
};
```

Behavior Effect, real but undesired syntax

```
void f(){
    A a;
    T& x= a.x;
    void(A::*g)()= &A::g; //method pointer; obvious why this is undesirable
    //...
};
```

Desired, unsupported syntaxes

```
void f(){
    A a;
    using a;
    //invalid/unsupported use of keyword
}
```

```
void f(){
    A a;
    [&a]{
        //...
        //lambdas only bring members into scope for keyword this
    }();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  You're basically unencapsulating which   I don't see people trying to do.

Comment: FWIW, for class member variables you can use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to make it easier to get aliases.

Comment: it simply saves a lot of typing effort. I use data orientation so encapsulation isnt a concern for me.

Comment: Structured bindings are close, but I would like the bindings to have the same name as their reference, so its still more tedious than ideal to type  
auto& [x,g]= { a.x, &a::g }; Additionally it cant automate a binding for each class member.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a satisfying nor reader-friendly solution. Its much better to explicitly declare references than do this.
However it only needs the variables to be brought into scope explicitly once.
Methods of the wrangler serve as the scope blocks.

```
struct wrangler{
    T& a;
    void(A::*g)()= &A::g;
    void f(){
        //...
    }
}
```